# Openvpn limit bandwidth

Tags: openvpn, bandwidth, tc, tap

I would like to ask you a question concerning openvpn and the possibility to increase the bandwidth in case I want to transfer files.

I have an openvpn server via which I connect to my data center. So, in some way, I want to have the ability to increase bandwidth when I'm going to transfer bigger than normal size of files.

From a google search, there are two options in my mind:

1)tc command
2)openvpn --shaper

In the first case, I haven't really understood how this command works.
In the latter, I have understood that I should run in this command on my openvpn server and limit bandwidth per user, per ip, etc.. But, I think that this should also happen on my tunnel interface. Is it true? And if this step should also be done, which is the way to configure the tunnel interface on Windows 7?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you mean to limit not increase ? right ?

Comment: To be more clear, to control traffic according to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows as client side, i would suggest to netlimiter software as it's easy to use, the tc is hard to configure specially in case of download as you would use polycer shaper.

with netlimeter you can control upload and download speed easily, from the client side.

Comment: This controls traffic only on the client side. If I want, as admin, control traffic to and from openvpn server for about 20 people as well, I wish to have more centralized and manageable solution. So, from the client side, it sounds good, but from the server side?

Comment: yes you are right then play with the tc, i have been playing with the tc for over a month it's too complicated and you need to understand everything about it. if the server is receving files you need to check traffic polycing with tc, if the server is sending files it's easier you need to check the traffic shapping options.

Comment: It's true that tc command seems to be a little bit complicated. My biggest problem is that it refuses the objects(filter, add, qdisk, etc..) and it appears problem with the kernel. So, may you know a good reference guide for this command?

Comment: http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.ultimate-tc.html